# Android EditText: cannot insert text between two emotion icons

Tags: android

I am using SpannableString to insert emotion icons into EditText. 
The following four cases are all OK:
(1) append text or emotion icon at the end of EditText, 
(2) insert emotion icon between text,
(3) insert emotion icon between existed emotion icons. 
(4) insert text between existed text.

But the problem is I cannot insert text between those icons. Here is my code and logcat info.

**(1) Add icon to EditText**:

```
Drawable d = UiUtil.getCachedDrawable(mActivity, EmResource.findResIdByTag(value));
            if (d != null) {
                d.setBounds(0, 0, w, w);

                String str = "<img src='" + value + "'/>";
                SpannableString ss = new SpannableString(str);
                ImageSpan span = new ImageSpan(d, ImageSpan.ALIGN_BOTTOM);
                ss.setSpan(span, 0, str.length(), Spannable.SPAN_INCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);

                contentEt.getText().replace(contentEt.getSelectionStart(), contentEt.getSelectionEnd(), ss);
            }
```

**(2) After inputing some icons, it looks like this (I have moved the cursor manualy after typing)**:

[image]

I have added a TextWatcher for this EditText. Log info from TextWatcher:

```
<img src='115'/><img src='116'/><img src='117'/><img src='118'/>
```

**(3) Then I press 'y' on the keyboard (in the position of previous screen shot). After that the cursor is moving but the text isn't shown. Like the following screen shot**:
[image]

But the log info shows that the text is inserted to EditText successfully.

```
<img src='115'/><img src='116'/>y<img src='117'/><img src='118'/>
<img src='115'/><img src='116'/>yy<img src='117'/><img src='118'/>
<img src='115'/><img src='116'/>yyy<img src='117'/><img src='118'/>
```

Any suggestions? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change Spannable.SPAN_INCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE to Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

As SpannableString content is immutable, it might not allow you to edit between two emojis, Instead of that try with [SpannableStringBuilder](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/SpannableStringBuilder.html) whose content and markup can both be changed. Hope it will help